# VS 2008 -- Using Relative paths in Build Properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nunit, relative-path

Long story short, I have a test project file (C# project) that contains the NUnit assemblies. When I hit F5, the build properties tell the project to launch NUnit and run the appropriate tests.

However, I work with a team and this project (including the NUnit binaries) are in subversion. Which means that when my partner pulls it down in a different location, the path to NUnit is different and thus it breaks.

Is there a "%PROJECTDIR%" constant or something that I can use in build properties to refer to the NUnit exe and make it work?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give,
Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go into Project - *ProjectName* settings
- Select Build Events
- Click *Edit Pre-build ...* or *Edit Post-build ...*
- Click on *Macros >>*
- Double click on the path or file you need.